# Why does Abs return negative values?

Tags: bugs, complex, numerical-value

**Bug introduced in 5.2 or earlier and fixed in 12.2**

---

According to the documentation Abs[z] gives the absolute value of the real or complex number z and is also known as the modulus. As far as I'm aware for any definition of the absolute value, norm or modulus the range of the function is supposed to be the positive real numbers but it seems that Mathematica's Abs function also returns negative numbers:

```
r = Root[ -1 - 9 # -15 #^2 + #^3&, 3, 1 ];

N[r]
(* 15.5817 *)

r > 0
(* True *)

N[Abs[r]]
(* -15.5817 *)

Abs[N[r]]
(* 15.5817 *)
```

I know that `Simplify`, `Reduce` and others show similar behaviour when working with powers of complex numbers, whose numerical value may change due multivaluedness of complex powers, but here I did not ask for a symbolic simplification and even if I did, there should be no change in numerical value since the Abs function is inherently single valued.

So I wondered whether this is a design choice or an actual bug and
if it is a design choice, then how am I supposed to e.g. sort eigenvalues on magnitude and return a list positive magnitudes?

**EDIT**
I have contacted the customer service but they get different results when running the same code.
The full code I used is the following:

```
r = Abs @ Last @ SortBy[ Eigenvalues[{{0,1,0,0},{1,10,6,4},{0,6,4,3},{0,4,3,2}}], Abs @* N ];

N[r] < 0
(* True *)

r//InputForm
(* -Root[-1 - 9*#1 - 15*#1^2 + #1^3 & , 3, 1] *)

N[Abs[r]]
(* -15.5817 *)
```

The code that the person from the customer service ran is exactly the same but the output seems to be correct when he runs it.

The results I get have also been confirmed by someone using Mathematica 11.2.

Are there people who can confirm this behaviour?

Comment: This is bug. Interesting is that `N[Abs[ToRadicals[r]]]` is correct.

Comment: "how am I supposed to e.g. sort eigenvalues on magnitude". Use `SortBy[list, Abs[N[#]] &]` or `SortBy[list, Abs[N[#, prec]] &]` for arbitrary precision.

Comment: Look what Abs[r] returns. Please make a report to support@wolfram.com

Comment: Why are you using 3 arguments for the Root object? The third argument shouldn't be used, it should be set by Mathematica when the 2 argument Root object is evaluated.

Comment: @Carl the Root expression was the output of Eigenvalues[mat]. Since there's no problem with the eigenvalues function I left that part out.

Comment: @Bob the problem is that I don't really trust the Abs function anymore. This time I got an incorrect result using N @* Abs but who's to tell that next time Abs @* N behaves incorrectly?

Comment: Workaround  `N[RealAbs[r]] (*15.5817*)`

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using, and on what OS? I get `0` as the 3rd argument of that `Root`, and the result is correct. If I change that 0 to 1 manually, I get a negative result.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem either with Mma 11.2 or with 12.1. The only way I can reproduce it is if I set the 3rd argument manually. @CarlWoll What does that 3rd undocumented argument do, actually?

Comment: I get the correct results in Mathematica 12.1.

Comment: "The results I get have also been confirmed by someone using Mathematica 11.2." Does this refer to the first code block or the second?

Comment: This has been internally reported as a bug, and bug tagging would be appropriate.

Comment: @Gert You wrote: "The results I get have also been confirmed by someone using Mathematica 11.2." I see exactly the same behavior using Mathematica 5.2 and 8.0.4 on Win-x64.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a bug that will be fixed in the nearest release of Mathematica. It affects Abs/Sign of positive Root objects with third argument 1, for which the real root isolation algorithm produces an isolating interval with the left end point 0.